# XSL - Cannot add a namespace to the root node

Tags: xslt, html-agility-pack

I have a html, I want to parse it to xml using html-agility-pack library. Here's the xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <BusinessDetail>
      <Name>
        <xsl:value-of select="//span[@class='pp-place-title']/span" />
      </Name>
      <Address>
        <xsl:value-of select="//span[@class='pp-headline-item pp-headline-address']/span"/>
      </Address>
      ...
    </BusinessDetail>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I just want to add a namespace to the root node. The expected output is:

```
<BusinessDetail xmlns:g="http://myurl.com">
  <Name>
    ...
  </Name>
  ..
</BusinessDetail>
```

So change my xls to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <BusinessDetail xmlns:g="http://myurl.com">
      <Name>
        <xsl:value-of select="//span[@class='pp-place-title']/span" />
      </Name>
      <Address>
        <xsl:value-of select="//span[@class='pp-headline-item pp-headline-address']/span"/>
      </Address>
      ...
    </BusinessDetail>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the namespace does not appear in the output. Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that the output you are trying to create makes no sense! Think about the meaning of the following document:

```
<BusinessDetail xmlns:g="http://myurl.com">
  <Name>
    ...
  </Name>
  ..
</BusinessDetail>
```

You are defining a namespace prefix 'g' and mapping it to the URI `http://myurl.com`, however, your document does not contain any elements that are defined as being within this namespace! The output of the XSLT is quite rightfully stripping out this redundant namespace declaration. Did you mean to do this intead:

```
<BusinessDetail xmlns="http://myurl.com">
  <Name>
    ...
  </Name>
  ..
</BusinessDetail>
```

This ensures that `BusinessDetail` and all its child elements are  in the `http://myurl.com` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the namespace to the stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:g="http://myurl.com">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <BusinessDetail>
      <Name>
        <xsl:value-of select="//span[@class='pp-place-title']/span" />
      </Name>
      <Address>
        <xsl:value-of select="//span[@class='pp-headline-item pp-headline-address']/span"/>
      </Address>
      ...
    </BusinessDetail>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, unless you specify any node that uses that namespace (your example doesn't, beyond defining it) it will not show in the output.

Comment: Hi - I disagree, you do not have to add the namespace to the xsl:stylesheet element, it can appear anywhere in the document. But yes, you are right, unless it is used, it will not appear in the output!

Comment: @ColinE perhaps that was bad wording on my part, reinforced by a an example that reinforced that specific case. At least I didn't go with my first draft that including namespace aliasing :)